# Changing return value

Tags: c++, function, return

I'm new to functions and trying to get the hang of return values.

I've made a function that prints a text but I want it to return a value depending on what's going on in the actual function.

This is an example:

```
int function(char a)
{
    int b = 0;

    if(a == 'a')
    {
        b++;
    }

        cout << "Example";

    if(b == 1){
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

However in this scenario, the return value will be "stuck" at 0 and won't change to 1. Is there a way to make the return value dependable of what happens in the function or is this not how it's supposed to be done?

EDIT: This is the code I'm working on. Basically it's a game of "Hangman" in Swedish. What I want is for the "wordCheck" function to return a value if all the letters are filled (and the word is completed) but right now it only return 0, even if "nC" is 4.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int wordCheck(char word[4], int c)
{
    int nC = 0, a;
    if(c != 1)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            if (word[i] == NULL)
            {
                word[i] = '_';
            }

            else if (word[i] != '_')
            {
                nC++;
            }
        }

        cout << "Ordet: "<< word[0] << " " << word[1] << " " << word[2] << " " << word[3] << endl << endl;
    }
    if(nC == 4){
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"");

    char guess = 'l', word[50] = "bajs", letter[4] = {NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL}, null[4] = {NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL};
    int i = 0, d = wordCheck(null, 1);

    do
    {
        i++;
        system("cls");
        cout << "**********HÄNGA GUBBE**********" << endl;
        cout << "*******************************" << endl;
        cout << "*********GISSA PÅ ORDET********" << endl;
        cout << "-------------------------------" << endl << endl;
        wordCheck(letter, 0);
        cout << "Gissning " << i << " : ";
        cout << d;
        cin >> guess;

        if (guess == word[0])
        {
            letter[0] = 'B';
        }
        else if (guess == word[1])
        {
            letter[1] = 'a';
        }
        else if(guess == word[2])
        {
            letter[2] = 'j';
        }
        else if (guess == word[3])
        {
            letter[3] = 's';
        }
    } while (wordCheck(null, 1) != 1);


    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

(cout << d  is just for debugging the return value, also bare in mind the code is not polished, it's a work in progress)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight My bad, I edited the post. It was a typo.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: How is it "stuck"? Did you try `function('a')`?

Comment: @crashmstr I've shared my code, maybe I have made a mistake somewhere else, I'm not sure.

Comment: @user2166357: The way you have coded it, there is no way that `checkWord()` can return 0 when `NC` is 4, like you claim. Did you try running your code in a debugger to see what it is *actually* doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i am not wrong you have **passed value to c as 1** in wordcheck function and because of that your if condition is not running which is not exactly increasing the value of nC ...thats why you are always getting 0 in return.

You have passed 1 to int c

```
 wordcheck(NULL,1)
```

and then checked `if(c!=1)` then `nC++` which is actually not happening and your nC remains 0, so in the next if condition your `else { return 0; }` is giving the return value

Comment: Oh yes sorry that's my bad, that's what I meant :P

Comment: so does this solves your problem?

Comment: No, if I print the return value in the main function (for example), it says "0", not "1".

Comment: share your main() function too please

Comment: I'll share my code instead, maybe I've done something else that's wrong.

Comment: But I have tried debugging it by printing text where "return 1" is in the wordcheck function and when nC is 4, the text is printed but the return value doesn't seem to change.

Comment: try changing your  if (c!=1) condition to  if (c!=0)

Comment: The reason I have the "c" variable is to be able to choose if I want to print the cout when I call the function. When I want to get the return value I don't want to actually print the cout. The if(nC == 4) statement is still activated when nC is 4.

Comment: That seems to be the case actually! Thank you for the help! I was unsure if the nC value would be stored but I guess not. Thanks again.

Answer (score -1):

In your do while loop, you should be sending your letter variable rather than your null variable because that is the array you want to validate.

Comment: Yeah, but that does not seem to help my problem.